# Why ireport don't open the open dialog

Tags: java, java-7, ireport

I'm trying to open a report file with ireport 4.5.1. But the "open file" dialog does not appear. If i click on File -> Open the program is terminated immediately.

When i click "Add Jar" in the classpath, the same happens.

I have windows 10 installed. I have set the jdkhome to my jdk-7-U-80 path. But I have additionally installed JDK 8 U 144.

I have checked the log files. But no error was logged.

What is the problem?

Comment: IMO this question should be on Superuser.

Comment: @Roy Did you try to use iReport with jre5 or jre6?

Comment: No. I dont tried jre5 or jre6. My colleague has also jdk 7 installed. His installation works fine.